# Possible to have a new table for every row in another table? (SQL)

Tags: sql, database

The only way I can think of doing it, since what I want to do is have a database of all the companies, and their respective information, then have another database per each company that sorts their orders and jobs, Is there a cleaner way than creating a table for each element in the company list table? If not, how would I go about doing this?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle? ("SQL" is not a DBMS, it's a query language)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create trigger on yourdb for insert

then inside the trigger

create table and insert int it the specific row

Comment: Thanks, that's about all I needed to know!

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit confusing.  It seems that you may want to add the company id as a key on all the relations that exist.  This would allow you to keep various company information in the same table structure and select from it by filtering on the company id.

Comment: Yeah actually, sorry about that I was trying to find a way to put it to words. But what you're suggesting is create a table with all of the orders/jobs and each row/job has a company number then when you go looking for a certain job persay filter by the company number? While this makes sense to do I want to know is there some sort of privacy leak in doing this? Does it become any less secure by storing multiple companies in one file?

Comment: sorry i never saw this.  There are several ways to implement security in this case depending on data access requirements.  Best case is your application is in total control of access in which case the data is as secure as your application.  It may not even be necessary to expose the customer id outside of the server implementation of your app.  Other alternatives might be to implement secured partitioned views on your tables using a schema per customer.